# Cross-browser Issue?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have been working on this website for a couple days now, until i did what most web developers fear, look at the site with other browsers, such as IE and Firefox. For some reason, the logo ticker in Firefox is not dropped down like it would be in Google Chrome. [Here is the website](http://fear.novaprogramming.com). I have tried to fix it on my own, looking through my source code, but found nothing i did wrong. What could be causing this issue in Firefox?

here is my CSS:

```
.list_carousel {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 0 30px 60px;
    width: 360px;
}
.list_carousel ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.list_carousel li {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 50px;
    height: 75px;
    line-height:75px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:6px;
    float: left; 
}
.list_carousel li img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.list_carousel li img:hover{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
}
.list_carousel.responsive {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
```

Nice Google Chrome:
[image]

And FireFox:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: More than happy to, hold on one second.

Comment: Because you are floating the 2 available elements in the div, the container div does not have the height set. You would need to do the clearfix

Comment: @Doorknob images have been uploaded.

Comment: @Sushanth-- what do you mean?

Comment: Try using `clear: both;` on the containers.

Comment: @RichardA wow, can not beleive that was a simple fix. Also, can you tell me why in IE, the css animated bar for my slider is not working. It works on all browsers except IE.

Comment: @EliteGamer No idea. Honestly, stuff NEVER works in IE. I'm surprised that my own project works in IE7 even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
clear: both;
```

to `.list_carousel`, that'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment above! Really, nothing does work in IE. Thanks for answering my Question.

Comment: No problem! Ever since I discovered with `clear` actually does, I've been using it so much with webdesign. Use it in conjunction with `float` and you're set!

Answer (score 1):

If all the elements inside the Container are `floated` then the container will not have any height.

Add the class `clearfix` to the `<div class="LogoContainer"`

```
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before , .clearfix:after{
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after{
    clear: both;
}
```

This should solve the issue on the all the browsers.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)